# Can AMD and NVIDIA display cards work together on linux?

Tags: linux, x11, graphics, display-settings

I know that two AMD graphics cards/two NVIDIA graphics cards can work together ,e.g. in xinerama/crossfire/multi-view.

But if I have one AMD graphics card and one NVIDIA graphics card, can I use them together on one platfrom simultaneously? How can I configure it?

PS. I am asking about the closed source drivers. Not the open source drivers. 
Did anybody try and success?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, and depending on your distribution, it should work out of the box. At least with open source drivers. I dón't know if the closed source drivers will behave oddly, but they shouldn't.

Yet, Xinerama is not what you want to do anymore. The Randr extension takes care of aranging monitors. You can use tools like `arandr` to align your screens using a GUI.

Comment: thanks for your answering, learnt!
actually i want know if amd and nvidia'closed source drivers can work together.
I asked one engineer in AMD that he says 'cannot',because the different mechanism of openGL loader fail to work together.
But i have not had a chance to try myself.

Comment: Well, the AMD engineer is probably right. And I think I remember that at least the AMD driver comes with its own libGL. Another reason not to use the CS drivers.

Comment: only you answered my question,cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have gtx 770 and HD 4850
when i install nvidia driver (not nouveau). My system freezes after grub.

you must remove radeon driver(opensource) or edit grub "radeon.modeset=0"

and
I dont try this article (beceause my radeon card old and its not support opencl for blender. i use for it for kvm.)
https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-10-12/both-nvidia-gtx-and-amd-radeon-on-linux/

sory for my bad english.